# Why is bootstrap not in wwwroot\lib\bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bower

I have just install Boostrap with command: *bower install bootstrap --save*

Bootstrap is under Dependecies/Bower, but not under wwwroot/lib/bootstrap does anyone know how I get the bootstrap in the wwwroot/lib/ folder?

My project is ASP.NET Core 2.0

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the file .bowerrc is missing (it is not automatic created when the Bower init command is made).

Add the .bowerrc file manuel by:

- 'Add new item' -> JSON file
- Name it: .bowerrc
- In the file add code:    {  "directory": "wwwroot/lib" }